Getting all values from a certain node in json using python
I hava a large json response on an api call using pytest. I want to pick up all hpsIds and all ids and "store it somewhere" to be used as parameters in a subsequent request.
[
 {
   "hpsId": 10032,
   "powerPlant": {
     "name": "Svartisen",
     "id": 67302,
      "regionId": 40,
     "priceArea": 4,
     "timeSeries": null,
      "units": [
            {
            "generatorName": "Svartisen G1",
            "componentId": 673021,
            "timeSeries": null
            },
        {
        "generatorName": "Svartisen G2",
         "componentId": 673022,
         "timeSeries": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
   "hpsId": 10037,
   "powerPlant": {
     "name": "Stølsdal",
     "id": 16605,
     "regionId": 20,
     "priceArea": 2,
     "timeSeries": null,
     "units": [
       {
         "generatorName": "Stølsdal G1",
         "componentId": 166051,
      "timeSeries": null
       }
     ]
   }
 },
.....

Using this I can obtain the 0th element in the response structure:
hpsId = response.json()[0]["hpsId"]

But I want to get al the hpsids and all the ids in the request saved to "something as maybe a list og dict? to be able to access later.
I guess a for-loop around the response running for as many elements there is in the response, say 1000, putting that condition in the expression:
hpsId = response.json()[0-1000]["hpsId"]

I know this is pseudo-code but any ideas?
working request now:
def test_get_powerplant():
global hpsId
global powerplantId
# Act:
response = get_requests(token, '/mfrr-eam/api/mfrr/eam/powerplant/all')
try:
    hpsId = response.json()[0]["hpsId"]  # Get the hpsId
    print("HPS Ids: ", hpsId)
    print(response.text)
except KeyError:
    print("Unable to get hpsID")
try:
    powerplantId = response.json()[0]["powerPlant"]["id"]  # Get the powerplant id
    print("PP Ids: ", powerplantId)
except KeyError:
    print("Unable to get powerplantId")
# Assertion:
assert response.status_code == 200  # Validation of status code


You can just loop over the json you get from requests.json() just like you do for a normal python dict and get the hspId from the dict at each iteration.

simply use for-loop or list comprehension - ie, all_ids = [item["hpsId"] for item in response.json()]

if you need to search something more complex then you may search special modules for this or external tools like jq

Simply use for-loop
data = response.json()

all_hpsIds = []
all_powerplantIds = []

for item in data:
    all_hpsIds.append(item["hpsId"])
    all_powerplantIds.append(item["powerPlant"]["id"])

or list comprehension
data = response.json()

all_hpsIds = [item["hpsId"] for item in data]

all_powerplantIds = [item["powerPlant"]["id"] for item in data]

You could also keep values as pairs:
data = response.json()

all_ids = [ (item["hpsId"], item["powerPlant"]["id"]) for item in data ]

or as dictionary
data = response.json()

all_ids = { item["hpsId"]:item["powerPlant"]["id"] for item in data }


If you want to save all hpsId and id into lists:
data = response.json()
hpsids = [datum['hpsId'] for datum in data]
ids = [datum['powerPlant']['id'] for datum in data]

